# Querying and working with Cursors in SQLite on Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Not sure if I'm the only one who feels this...

I find working with the sqlite api in android a complete pain in the butt and pretty soul destroying. Has anyone got any tips/helpers to make my life easier?

Here's an example of what I'm talking about.

```
//create code

db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + CUSTOMER_TABLE_NAME + " ("
                        + GENERIC_ID_KEY+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, " 
                        + PHONE_KEY + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
                        + CUSTOMER_NAME_KEY+ " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                        + EMAIL_KEY + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                        + ADDRESS_KEY +" TEXT);");


//get code
    Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(true, CUSTOMER_TABLE_NAME, new String[] {GENERIC_ID_KEY,
                        ADDRESS_KEY, PHONE_KEY, EMAIL_KEY,CUSTOMER_NAME_KEY}, GENERIC_ID_KEY + "=" + customerDbId, null,
                                null, null, null, null);

        Customer customer = new Customer (customerDbId, (CharSequence)mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CUSTOMER_NAME_KEY)),
                            (CharSequence)mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PHONE_KEY)),
                            (CharSequence)mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(EMAIL_KEY)),
                            (CharSequence)mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ADDRESS_KEY)));
```

This a simple exmple of creating a simple customer object from a db query; some of my code is far nastier than this. Hand crafting queries in this way leads to all sort of errors I don't find until runtime.

Any tips greatly appreiciated!

Ok after the tips below I now have this:

```
  db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE customer (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, " 
                        + "phone_number INTEGER NOT NULL, "
                        + "name TEXT NOT NULL, "
                        + "email TEXT NOT NULL, "
                        + "address TEXT);");


    //get code
String q = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE _id = " + customerDbId +";"
        Cursor mCursor = mDb.rawQuery(q, null);

        Customer customer = new Customer (mCursor);
```

in the Customer, I access the fields like this

```
mName = cursor.getString(2)
```

Ahh, I feel much better :)

Cheers
Si

Comment: Well, no offense, sometimes you actually have to write some code :) Mobile Platforms don't provide the same abstraction as desktop operating systems.

Comment: ah, that `getColumnIndexOrThrow` thing is killing me... couldn't they create a `getString` overload that takes the column name directly ???

Answer (score 39, accepted):

1. Don't use model objects if you do not have to. I've concluded, unless there is significant business logic that can only be represented via model objects, that they are more trouble than they are worth in a mobile platform.
2. Assuming you are stuck with model objects, have them load themselves out of a `Cursor`, rather than trying to pass in umpteen parameters.
3. `query()` is much more verbose than `rawQuery()` for limited added value, if you know SQL.
4. Assembling your `CREATE TABLE` clause via concatenation is self-imposed pain, not mandated by SQLite or Android.
5. Don't use `getColumnIndexOrThrow()` from custom-written code. You wrote the query, so you know what order the columns are coming back in. Only use something like `getColumnIndexOrThrow()` if you are creating some abstract library that does not know the details of the Cursor it was given.
6. `String` inherits from `CharSequence`, so all those casts can be dropped.

Comment: thanks, rawQuery()! I'd missed that, looks very useful. I'll also re-think my model objects as I'm not stuck with them.

Comment: Where were you a few weeks ago before I had figured all this out for myself?? Nice to have confirmation of what I had already suspected but it's a shame that all the Google docs seem to follow this extremely convoluted route.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, can you please confirm my understanding of your answer? Are you saying that modelled objects are not necessary when using say Cursors as the Cursor is the data object, and unless you need to manipulate the data, simply use the Cursor? I'm finding little use for modelled objects in my SQLite backed app, as I've modelled my SQLite tables into "objects", and when I return one as a Cursor, that's all I seem to need. Do you concur? If you care for more details, this is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791349/oop-modelled-objects-in-a-database-driven-app

Comment: what is the alternative to using models?

Comment: @J.K.: First, bear in mind that this question and answer are five years old, which is an eternity in terms of Android. Assuming you're willing to deal with memory management, you're welcome to copy your database results into POJO models, manually or through an Android-centric ORM. But you don't absolutely need POJO models, just using the raw `Cursor` as the source of model data.

Comment: great, because I always keep my database operation classes in separate files and send the results from querying via listeners :)

Answer (score 3):

I tested a lot of my SQL in SQLite before copying them over to Android as strings.  It's easier for me to debug when I can directly interact with the command line.

Another technique I use is saving as much of my queries as possible as string constants or  string resources.

You also don't need SQL such as `INTEGER NOT NULL` since SQLite uses duck typing/manifest typing.  It does help for type affinity though..