# Android: Text primary key with different name

Tags: android, sqlite, primary-key

I have an existing Windows app for which I'm writing an Android port. The app uses a unique string as the primary key, but the SQLite methods in Android all seem to work with integers and a column names _id, whereas my ID column isn't called this. Is there a way to let Android know I have a key with a different column name?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to let Android know I
>   have a key with a different column
>   name?

No.

So long as you avoid the use of `CursorAdapter`, I think you will be OK. Otherwise, you will need to create a separate unique `_ID` integer column. You don't necessarily need to use that as a primary key, but `CursorAdapter` and friends will want it.

Comment: I eventually went with Android's naming scheme. There werre some good tips at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122679/android-sqllite-tips