# Android How to Change Many Class Variables Efficiently? (Maybe I'm Bastardizing OOP?)

Tags: android, oop, class, variables, object

I have an Android Class called Receipt, it's modeled off a typical Receipt you'd get in a retail environment and includes the following Class variables:

```
receipt_number
date_ordered
date_paid
item_quantity
item_type
item_sku
item_price
total_price
customer_id
customer_name
clerk_id
clerk_name
```

Whew... there's a lot. I'm just becoming accustom to OOP and while I love the idea of using a Receipt data Class to store the properties of a Receipt, I fear I am using an object just for the sake of using an object and not using data Classes appropriately.

Why? Well, I have another method in another Class which I feed my Receipt object to. Once fed to this other Class, the Receipt data is used to fill out a View which allows the user to edit said Receipt (data from the Receipt fills out EditText boxes which can be changed, then saved). The problem is that the code is getting ridiculous for updating a Receipt. I've got a helper method in Receipt for virtually every variable above (e.g. setClerkId(), setCustomerName(), setItemSku(), etc. etc.) and when I update a Receipt, I find myself calling all these methods and it's turning into a huge rats nest.

Surely I am missing the boat here, and probably by a long-shot. There must be a more sane way to feed in all the values of my new Receipt (it's really an update of the old object) without manually updating each variable using a helper method? I guess I'd be a little bit surprised (no, a lot surprised) if this is the correct way of doing this.

Any push in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: A good start might be to identify the separate objects that are actually represented by a receipt - the item, the customer, the clerk, and consider modelling them separately (How often does the clerk change, for instance? Why re-enter it every time?). Objects should be largely concerned with a single item (and ideally with a single responsibility.)

Comment: Aha, so I am defining my objects too generally you believe? I think you're definitely on the right track because yes, various items never change, and therefore perhaps they should be separate objects afterall.. Now I'm looking at my application in an entirely different light.

Comment: I found the best way to deal with Objects from a SQLite database is as follows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122679/querying-and-working-with-cursors-in-sqlite-on-android

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right I guess. I an object has a lot of named properties then you'll have to do a lot of get/set.

You can simplify that if you don't need to access each individually if you put them all into  single (or several) `ArrayList<String>`/`String[]` or even other objects. Whatever you feel is an appropriate representation of your data.

Or you take a `HashMap` instead of your class and store them like so:

```
HashMap<String, String> hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
hashmap.put("receipt_number", value);
String value = hashmap.get("receipt_number");
```

That results in a more dynamic way to store values.

Comment: So.. one says, yes, one says no. I guess it's preference?

Comment: It's a lot of preference :) If your class does nothing than just hold basic data and has no functionality then it's fine if you optimize it for storage e.g. with lists. If you intent do give your classes further functionality you could separate them into e.g. Item, Date, Customer & Clerk. But that makes using the data even more tedious if all you want is to set them to an EditText and read them back from there.